# How can a contributed setting have a multiline textarea in the settings UI with a reset button?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, package.json

I am developing an extension.
The extension has a two parameters for the user to input data via the Settings.

Is it possible to set the textbox to a textarea (like in html) and have a reset to default button?

I created these two fields. But I wish to set textareas instead of textboxes and a reset button on each one. I don't even know if it's possible.
[image]

What the package.json looks like
[image]

Comment: "_Is it possible to set the textbox to a textarea (like in html) and have a reset to default button?_" that's actually two questions! please split your multiple questions into one question post each :) Or are you saying that you know how to do each on its own, but don't know how to do both in combination?

Comment: how do you suppose to store the content of the textarea in the settings? Not all settings can be modified with the GUI, edit the JSON file

Comment: type `string` is a textbox in the GUI, `array of string` is a listbox in the GUI

Answer (score 0):

You can get multiline setting text inputs. See https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_59#_multiline-string-settings

> To add support for a multiline string setting in the Settings editor, add `"editPresentation": "multilineText"` as a key-value pair to the string setting. Changing a string setting to be multiline will cause the Settings editor to render the setting value in a multiline text area instead of a single-line input box.

As for a reset button, it already exists: To reset settings, click the gear icon in the settings UI for the setting, and click the "Reset Setting" action button.

Answer (score -1):

I’m sorry to say, but these are not possible. There is no *textarea* kind of setting, nor the possibility to customize the inputs with a new button.

There is however an open issue requesting the same textarea you asked for (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/183025). I suggest you to subscribe/upvote to follow it future.

And about the reset button you asked, in fact, it already exists. Simply click over the setting and you will see an engine icon. Click it and a `Reset Setting` item is available.

[image: reset setting]

Hope this helps